# When should I use ; instead of && in command line interface?

Tags: command-line

I always been using `&&` but just saw someone uses `;`.
What is the difference?  When should I use `;` or `&&`?

Comment: There seems to be a big confusion here. `;` and `&&` are not equivalent. Please add the example where you saw this, it must make sense in the context of the problem

Comment: duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/100704/63453

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic difference is that all commands separated by `;` would be executed whereas when commands are separated by `&&` then the subsequent command would be executed only if the previous exited with a return code of `0`.

As such, when you say:

```
command1; command2; command3
```

the shell executes `command1`, then `command2` and when the latter is also complete `command3`.

On the other hand,

```
command1 && command2 && command3
```

causes `command1` to be executed.  If it is successful, i.e. it exits with a return code of `0`, then `command2` is executed.  Similarly, `command3` is executed if the previous command executed successfully.

The latter construct is useful when you want to execute commands conditionally.